# Meaning of marking "armonici"

Tags: terminology

In particular, looking at the cello part from the 1924 Casa Ricorda edition of Respighi's Ancient Airs and Dances (Universal Music Co).   Third movement,  there's a divisi with both parts playing a G one octave apart.  The notes are written normally (not marked as they would if to be played open-string harmonics), but "armonici" is written.  My feeling is this is just encouraging us to play sweetly and in perfect harmony.  Any ideas?

Edit: FWIW our conductor (Valerie Taylor of Berklee) agrees they should be played as harmonics.

Comment: Google translate says armonici means harmonic in Italian.

Comment: Hey @Carl, although you describe the passage of music really well, it would be great to see it, to get an idea of those notes in context...

Comment: http://imslp.org/wiki/Antiche_danze_et_arie_per_liuto,_Suite_No.2_(Respighi,_Ottorino). Carl is talking about the first bar of pg. 41. The written notes are G above and below middle C, held for 3-and-a-quarter bars; "armonici" is in parentheses. Under the circumstances, I suspect Respighi means "armonici naturali", i.e., open harmonics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the mark "armonici" is a *plural noun*, i.e., "harmonics". The cello part shows the cellos divisi, with the indication dead in the middle between the staves (see [the cello part](http://imslp.org/wiki/Special:ImagefromIndex/349623) - fair warning though, it downloads immediately). Presumably he's asking for natural harmonics written at pitch. The harmonics are playable on either the C or G strings - nothing too fancy, especially coming off a low G in the previous phrase (most likely played on the C string - the lower cellos wouldn't need to change position at all; the upper cellos would only need a small shift to take the higher harmonic on the G string; and they would avoid an open string in a ***pp*** passage).